# Why does changing a ViewModel property to a function cause different emission behavior with collectAsStateWithLifecycle in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-room, kotlin-flow

I'm using the following line of code to pull data from a room database inside my composable function:

val messagesUiState: MessagesUiState by messageViewModel.allMessages.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

If I change the view model property to a function, I get multiple emissions from the flow and compose will re-render multiple times causing the ui to flicker:

val messagesUiState: MessagesUiState by messageViewModel.allMessages().collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

The reason I would like to use a function instead is so that I can pass a parameter to the Room database.

allMessages inside the ViewModel

```
 val allMessages: StateFlow<MessagesUiState> = chatRepository.getAllMessages()
        .map(MessagesUiState::Success)
        .stateIn(scope = viewModelScope,
            started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
            MessagesUiState.Loading)
```

Query to Room:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM message")
    fun getAll(): Flow<List<Message>>
```

When I change all messages as follows, I get multiple emissions and compose re-renders multiple times. I want it to just emit once so that the ui does not flicker with each emission:

```
fun allMessages(): StateFlow<MessagesUiState> = chatRepository.getAllMessages()
        .map(MessagesUiState::Success)
        .stateIn(scope = viewModelScope,
            started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
            MessagesUiState.Loading)
```

and

```
val messagesUiState: MessagesUiState by messageViewModel.allMessages().collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
```

Can anyone help me understand this behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use a property, it is only initialized once (at class instantiation) and the value is cached in an internal field. Any subsequent call will return the same flow.

When you use a function, it is computed every time it is called. A new flow is created every time you call the function version.

Comment: Thanks! I see now. I had to cache the state flow inside the viewmodel. The composable function kept re-rendering because each call to allMessages() was returning a new flow causing a re-render every time. Not sure if there is a better approach. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try `distinctUntilChanged()` operator to filter out the repetitions of the same value emit.

```
fun allMessages(): 
    StateFlow<MessagesUiState> = chatRepository
                                .getAllMessages()
                                .distinctUntilChanged()
                                .map(MessagesUiState::Success)
                                .stateIn(
                                    scope =viewModelScope, 
                                    started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000), MessagesUiState.Loading
                                )
```